# Error in start Vue with Vite: Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code eof-in-element-that-can-contain-only-text

Tags: javascript, html, npm, vuejs3, vite

When I run the `npm run dev` command I get the error:

`Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code eof-in-element-that-can-contain-only-text`

I think it's a Vite bug, but I'm not too sure, by the way, I also get errors when I run npm audit fix --force:

```
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from @storybook/addon-essentials@5.3.21
```

However, these are storybook errors, and not vite/parse5, so there should be no problem. I comment it to give more context of the problem.

I already tried to reinstall node_modules y updating vite.

- File index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./public/vue.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue App<title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- File package.json

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tabler/icons-vue": "^2.20.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^5.3.21",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.14-next.2",
    "@storybook/vue3": "7.0.12",
    "@storybook/vue3-vite": "7.0.12",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "4.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "storybook": "^6.5.16",
    "typescript": "5.0.2",
    "vite": "4.4.1",
    "vitest": "0.32.4",
    "vue-tsc": "1.4.2"
  }
}
```